# Adding worker-loader breaks Webpacker

Tags: webpack, webpacker, worker-loader

I'm using [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader) 
in a Rails / Webpacker setup. `worker-loader` is an easy way to use Web-workers in Webpack.

`yarn add worker-loader`

[As per Webpacker instructions](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md#loaders), I'm adding this loader to `environments.js`.

```
environment.loaders.append('worker', {
  test: /\.worker\.js$/,
  use: 'worker-loader',
});
```

and finally, adding the `.worker.js` extension to `webpacker.yaml`

When running the app, or building directly via `./bin/webpack --progress`
I'm running out of Heap memory, or it gets stuck and never finishes.

If I comment out the `worker-loader` line in `environments.js`, Webpacker finishes up quickly without error.

Anyone run into anything similar?